# Suspicious binoculars

Tags: binoculars

I was thinking to buy some general purpose high magnification binocs, to look at the moon or sunsets and stuff. I have not any professinal or even hobbyist knowledge of photography. I read that when a set of binocs is presented as AxB, then A is the magnification and B is the lens diameter.

In many of my country's online marketplaces, I have found a product that is suspiciously high performance and low price at the same time. The brand is Galileo and they are supposedly 80x120 priced at around 30 euro.

[This](https://www.skroutz.gr/c/273/kialia.html?order_by=popularity&order_dir=desc) is the largest site I've checked, has about 1000 binocs, and I've checked all of them. The product in question is [this](https://www.skroutz.gr/s/30590860/%CE%9A%CE%B9%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%B1-Galileo-80x120mm.html?from=best_sellers_tag).

My scam sense is tingling, because:

- In non-zoom binocs, the highest zoom I've noticed is 20x. That is a large gap until 80.
- A quick search gives me [this](http://www.galileooptics.com/) as the manufacturer's site. The logo matches. There is no mention of such product anywhere, although I admit the site does not seem well maintained and could be out of date.
- Also, I see on the manufacturer's site that all product have manufacturer codes. No such thing mentioned in any store of the product in question.
- The product photo, compared to others, certainly does not give a behemoth feel that a 120mm lens would. Actually, one of the shops states "lens diameter 7 cm"!

Can someone give a more informed opinion? Could those numbers be showing something else?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with photography.

Comment: Hmm, of the stack exchange network, I though here's where people with knowledge on lenses would be.

Comment: If you're not capturing a photograph, it's not photography.  Binocular optics work on top of another lens (human eye), so are not the same as typical camera optics.  Maybe physics/optics would be appropriate.

Comment: Maybe this is one for Skeptics.SE?

Comment: The various pictures in the linked ad are of two different size binoculars.

Comment: If binocular specifications are like the ones for photo lenses, 20x zoom does not indicate the magnification. It indicates the difference between the smallest and larges magnification. It could mean e.g. from magnification 4 to magnification 80.

Comment: @RoelSchroeven These are not zoom binoculars, though.

Comment: Here's a [helpful link from B&H](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/outdoors/buying-guide/the-bh-binocular-buying-guide). I bought a cheap pair of binoculars in 2020, and, without knowing much about binoculars, I found it very helpful to shop at a brick-and-mortar specialist store, where I could try them out in person and ask questions of the assistant who knew what to recommend at my budget. I've been happy with my cheapo ones, for their intended purpose.

Comment: If you look at the sun with binoculars, that might be the last thing you'll ever see.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with photo

Answer (score 3):

Apparently these binoculars are not 80 power by 120mm objectives.

Instead, the size of included cleaning cloth is 80 x 120 mm!

[image]

Comment: the image can't possibly reflect a binocular that was 80 power with a 120mm objective lens if it did exist you probably couldn't hand hold it
first because of its weight
second because of its high magnification scam or not the price is just too unrealistic

Comment: omg? Could you please provide a link of where you found that?

Comment: Then again 14° and 5m/10000m are not specifications of the cloth. In any case none of it gives my much confidence.

Comment: A real 80x120 would be a common 5" refractor -- typical one meter or so tube length.  Surely not binoculars.

Comment: In the product images 80x120 is written on the binocs. I guess it's just acoma missing in the description. These numbers are clearly not right.